# "React" Kendo DropdownList changing value doesn't set it as selected

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui

I have a react kendo dropdownlist as

```
                                <DropDownList
                                id="someCategoryType-dropdown"
                                name="someCategoryTypeDD"
                                value={someDetailsOutput.someCategoryType ?? props.someCategoryType}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                data={componentState.someCategoryTypeList}
                                textField="text"
                                dataItemKey="id"
                                defaultItem={Constants.DefaultItem}
                            />
```

I have a search button which when clicked, calls the API and returns the data (working correctly) and someDetailsOutput.someCategoryType is properly calculated. I know because I also show it on UI. Now as per React Kendo documentation, changing the value should show that item as selected value but it doesn't. I have verified that the exact same string (same casing) is in both someDetailsOutput.someCategoryType as well as one of the items in the dropdownlist. Anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear in the KendoReact documentation, but the value only works against the very object the data is tied to. You can't tie it to another object with the same value and expect it to work.

```
value={componentState.someCategoryTypeList.find(c => c.text === someDetailsOutput.someCategoryType) ?? componentState.someCategoryTypeList.find(c => c.text === props.someCategoryType)}
```